# Is there a way to verify jpa mappings at compile time with maven?

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa

I have java classes with @Table and @Column mapping annotations.  I'm currently using hibernate as the ORM.  I would like to use some kind of a compile\build time step to check all of the names (and preferably types too) against a live test database, preferably using maven.  Ideally the build will fail if there is a column name or table name in the annotations that is not defined in a particular table or database on the server.

Is there a way to pull this off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a JUnit test that will do

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("YOUR_TEST_PU");
```

In your test persistence.xml file add the line below:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
```

Like this the JPA will validate your schema with your code. If there is an error the test will break and your build too.